# Build REST APi with complex entity

Tags: rest, symfony

I'm building REST API for my system with complex entities that have many relationship with each other. I'm looking for a way to automatically return entities with one-to-many or many-to-many relationship or I have to do it by hand. Any suggestion? Thanks for your help

Comment: are you looking for a way to **find** entities with relations or are you looking for a way to **serialize** entities with relations? ...

Comment: Yes, i mean serialize entities. This is my first time building REST API so I don't know what's the best way to handle fetched entity and convert them to array, select which properties to return or not....

Comment: ... then dive into JMSSerializerBundle as suggested by @forgottenbas :)

Comment: FOSRestBundle could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JMS/Serializer](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle&ei=fXEAUqLZHPTQ4QTy3oGoBg&usg=AFQjCNEpCr6Fk72vpVQ9UGtGMSEZV0NE0g&sig2=cB2jwngSkP5786CAvwFYWg&bvm=bv.50310824,d.bGE) can serialize retations if you set [Array or ArrayCollection](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#type) type. You can install it with `php composer.phar require jms/serializer-bundle`. Read more at [documentation](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle).

Comment: Thanks, it's a good serializer to use. It worked well with annotation, but my entity mapping is XML. I followed instruction here http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/xml_reference but it's not work. Is there any config to activate XML support for exclusion policy?

Comment: `class` tag has `exclusion-policy` attribute, `property` has `groups`

Answer (score 0):

If you want an [Hateoas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS) architecture, you can use [FSCHateoasBundle](https://github.com/TheFootballSocialClub/FSCHateoasBundle) (which hooks the JMSSerializer).

You can set relations using annotation and embed resources as the property of the main resource.
This bundle will automatically add navigation links to these resources.